# Android parsing String to Date time with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, time

I have the String `11/08/2013 08:48:10`

and i use `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

and when im parsing it throws an exception : unparseable date

what's wrong with it ?

```
            String result = han.ExecuteUrl("http://"+han.IP+":8015/api/Values/GetLastChange"); 
            Log.d("Dal","result date time "+result); #result is 11/08/2013 08:48:10
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            try
            {

                convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(result);
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: done. han variable is just for getting results from url which returns the date

Comment: For new readers consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code runs fine on my desktop Java. I got `Fri Nov 08 08:48:10 CET 2013`.

Answer (score 30):

Its working try parse your date like this..

```
String dtStart = "11/08/2013 08:48:10";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
try {
    date = format.parse(dtStart);
    System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where is the difference between your answer and question?

Answer (score 4):

Working code is here.

You can use below code to convert from **String to Date**

```
String myStrDate = "11/08/2013 08:48:10";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(myStrDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For reverse, it means, to convert from **Date to String**

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = new Date();
        String datetime = myFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("Current Date Time in give format: " + datetime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more reference, regarding Date and Time formatting. Visit [developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

It’s not the answer that you asked for, but it should be the answer that other readers want in 2020 and onward.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    String result = "11/08/2013 08:48:10"; 
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(result, formatter);
    System.out.println("Parsed date and time: " + dateTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Parsed date and time: 2013-11-08T08:48:10

The `Date` class that you used is poorly designed and long outdated, so don’t use that anymore. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If you need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade just now, the conversion is:

```
    Instant i = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = DateTimeUtils.toDate(i);

    System.out.println("Converted to old-fashioned Date: " + oldfashionedDate);
```

> Converted to old-fashioned Date: Fri Nov 08 08:48:10 CET 2013

### What went wrong in your code?

> what's wrong with it ?

The only thing wrong with your code is you’re using the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFOrmat` and the poorly designed `Date` class. Which wasn’t wrong when you asked the question in 2013. java.time didn’t come out until 4 months later.

Your code is running fine. One may speculate that a leading space or the like in your string has prevented parsing. If this was the problem, try parsing `result.trim()` rather than just `result` since `trim()` returns a string with the leading and trailing whitespace removed.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. Only in this case the conversion to `Date` is a little simpler: `Date.from(i)`.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.