# Android : how to get now date time string in following format "2015-10-08T08:09:22.067+00:00"?

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone

I would like to ask how can i get string with 'now' date in the following format?

```
"2015-10-08T08:09:22.067+00:00" ?
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Refer to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here at the simpledateformat method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the simple date format to format your date string . For this, consider reading the [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) link .

But if you want just to change the string and get the time then just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it) link or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873864/android-parsing-string-to-date-time-with-simpledateformat) link

I hope this answer would help you.