# Error due unparseable date

Tags: java

I have the error in this line:

```
String mDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zZZZ yyyy").parse(myDate.toString()));
```

**Error:**

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Dec 14 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017" (at offset 0)

If the error happens due incorrectly pattern then what pattern will be proper for this format of date?

I know that many topics exist with similar problems. But the key to my questions is proper date format for my date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873864/android-parsing-string-to-date-time-with-simpledateformat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android parsing String to Date time with SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873864/android-parsing-string-to-date-time-with-simpledateformat)

Comment: My subject isn't duplicate. There is another date format.

Comment: See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should only have `EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy` iso `EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zZZZ yyyy`. So removing `ZZZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your default locale?

If you run this:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US)
            .parse("Thu Dec 14 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017"));
```

It will parse the date but if you run this:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.GERMAN)
            .parse("Thu Dec 14 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017"));
```

Because `Thu` and `Dec` are English words. So check your default locale because if you don't pass a local to `SimpleDateFormat` it will take the default(if you dig around ) as shown here inside `SimpleDateFormat`  class.

```
 Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
```

Comment: Yes, the error happens because Locale wasn't specified. Thank you!